# NullPointerException in LogCat?

Tags: android

Whenever I introduce the array, i get this error. I tried different array types...but no luck.

```
public class Classifytestclass2 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         int test2[] = null;
        for(int i=0;i<50;i++){
               test2[0]=1;
        }
    }
}
```

edit:
forgot to mention, the entire app crashes (force close.)

Comment: slukian has already pointed out the problem that's causing the error, though you should also know that you are just setting the first element of test2 to '1' 50 times, You probably want `test2[i] = 1;`

Comment: Accept it as answer because it solved your problem

Comment: I did that, but still got the error...fixed now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's normal to get a `NullPointerException` because you didn't initialize the array(). You have to do something like this:

```
int test2[] = new int[50];
```

to initialize an array with 50 elements.

Comment: Thanks again...i thought i did select you as the answer...prolly misclicked sorry

Answer (score 0):

what do you want to do with this

```
enter code here


for(int i=0;i<50;i++){
       test2[0]=1;
}
```

As this code sets the value of test2[0]=1; every time loop moves.
Please let me know, what exactly you want?